# Click specific button in table

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, chai, webdriver-io

I'm working with Webdriverio, Selenium and Javascript

In my frontend, I have three divs each containing a table with same classname (field_table).
The divs has id 0, 1 and 2 and same classname (receiver_field)

Every table contains a button with the same classname as well (delete-button).

That is because the tables are automaticly generated

In my Webdriverio Selenium test, I would like to click one of the tree buttons, so that I can delete one entry

But how do I navigate to only one button when they all have the same classnames?
I tried navigate via the id but I can't get it to work

```
    it('should be possible to delete on button click', function () {

    // Get receiver fields
    var fields = browser.elements('.form-control-list');
    expect(fields.value.length).to.equal(6);

    // Get only one table
    // Get that tables button
    // Click the button

    //expect(fields.value.length).to.equal(4);

});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: edit your code and remove the syntax errors first

Comment: - and then what? Any suggestions on how to solve the actual problem?

Comment: please create a [mcve] demonstrating your error in your question - it is impossible to see what the problem is without your html and the js you are using

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you an error - I'm just seeking guidance on how to write the test and how to click that one button inside the table

Comment: "fields" should be an array of webElements containing 3 elements, click on of them based on the position, something like: 
fields[1].click(..) ...

Comment: Hey there @LouiseNielsen! Here to help you debug the issue if the problem still stands. It's an easy selector fix, but I'll throw in other ways to tackle it too. Can you please add the `HTML` structure of the main container? ... else I'll go with an example based on your description of it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to get all the elements with the same class name into a list (or array), and then select the element you want to interact with from the list.

Eg.:

```
Elems = browser.findElementsByClassName("class_name")

Elems[0].click()
```

Adapt the above to JavaScript, I'm not that good with it. :)

Comment: It's not possible to do so when using browser...
It only uses methods like these: http://webdriver.io/api.html

Comment: Oh yes, I remember how awful WebdriverIO is now... I guess put findElementsByClassName in the Page Object, or wherever you locate webelements. The main thing is to locate all of the elements, put them in a list and iterate through that list. Actually you are already doing that. Look at the comment by mboullouz

Comment: @Alichino you remember badly, or you just never knew how to use the tool in the first place. WDIO has way more elegant syntax (**$ & $$** ftw!) Let's stop with the bias towards things we do not fully grasp. Also this is not a **framework** issue, it's a **selector** issue. So name-blaming's on you! :p